# Falling/Colliding Legos

Tags: animation, particles, physics, collision

I am trying to animate a scene in Blender that consists of Lego blocks falling and colliding with some text/objects.

I have tried two main approaches to this:

1. With particle systems rendering a collection of Lego objects. This runs quite well, but the particles do not collide the way they should. It appears they only collide when the center of the Lego (which I presume is the actual particle) collides, rather than the Lego object mesh.
2. By converting particles to real objects. This is largely unworkable as I cannot render it, even with just a few pieces, despite having an RTX 3060.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong and can provide more information as needed or provide screenshots of the scene. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try searching this site and on youtube for Rigid Body tutorials and tips.  That would be my approach.  Also, you would want to convert your text into a mesh object no matter what approach you use.

Comment: +1 james_t ... particles can collide just as a spheres (point with distance), for more advanced collision you need Rigid Body ... if you can't sim real objects you can try to sim a objects as a blocks (lowers), bake sim and switch data to hires model (it could work if you use Alt+D for duplicated object, that shares the same object data between objects)... but if you can't render just a few bricks ... hard to say...

Comment: could also use geometry nodes to convert a collection of objects to instances of a particular object…